# Want to add a value and remove on a single click using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a onclick function and adding a value to by paasing a value to it. If the value already exists den i remove that value from the list.

```
function send_value(str)
    {
    //alert(str);
    var sub_id = document.getElementById('selected_sub_id').value;
    //alert(sub_id.indexOf(str));
    if(sub_id.indexOf(str)==-1)
    {
        if(sub_id=="")
        {
            sub_id+=str;
        }
        else
        {
        sub_id+=',';
        sub_id+=str;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sub_id = sub_id.replace(str+",", "");
        sub_id = sub_id.replace(","+str, "");
        sub_id = sub_id.replace(str, "");
    }
    //alert(sub_id);
    document.getElementById('selected_sub_id').value=sub_id;
}
```

This is the function. Suppose i have the values 1,2,3,4 in the `selected_sub_id` and i am passing 5 to it, it will be stored as 1,2,3,4,5
now i am passing 24 it will be stored as 1,2,3,4,5,24
No suppose i want to remove 2, so when i send 2 to the function it removes all the occurrences of 2 so i am left with only 1,3,4,54...
kindly help me with this thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably want an array for this. It makes things much easier.

Create one first:

```
var arr = [];
```

Adding goes with `.push`:

```
arr.push(24);
```

Removing goes with `.splice` and `.indexOf` (the `1` means 'removing 1 element'):

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(24), 1);
```

Converting to a string goes with `.join`:

```
arr.join(); // 1,2,3,24 or something similar depending on elements
```

---

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ScBNQ/.

```
var arr = [];

// adding

arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);
arr.push(24);

// removing

arr.splice(arr.indexOf(2), 1);

// joining

arr.join(); // 1,3,24
```

Comment: How do i kno that the element I am send is in the array or not

Comment: @lucky123: `arr.indexOf(24)` will return `-1` if `24` is not in the array, otherwise it will return the index it is at.

Comment: `var arr = [];
 
 var arr = document.getElementById('selected_sub_id').value;
 //alert(sub_id.indexOf(str));
 if(arr.indexOf(str)==-1)
 {
   arr.push(str);
 }
 else
 {
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(str), str);
  arr.join();
 }
 //alert(sub_id);
 document.getElementById('selected_sub_id').value=arr;`

Iam doing it this way !!!! tell me if its wrong. it says `arr.push(str);` is not a function;

Comment: @lucky123: I should have been a little clearer. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ScBNQ/1/. You can combine add/remove into one button with what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @lucky123 from your code in your comment above, you are getting an error because your are assigning `arr` as an array and then immediately re-assigning it to `document.getElementById('selected_sub_id');` so of course `arr` doesn't have the `push` function.